# Is HTTPS traffic with self-signed certificate secure enough for desktop app to server connection?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

On my Apache server I've created a self-signed key and certificate pair with OpenSSL. I've also redirected all traffic to use HTTPS.

And on my C# app, I'm using something like this to send and receive data.

```
StringContent encodedContent = new StringContent(str, null, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.PostAsync("https://myserverip/main.php", encodedContent)
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(URL, encodedContent).Result;
```

On top of that I've also implemented my own AES encryption using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) both on the server side and client side.

But all this encryption and decryption is giving me a lot of headaches.

My question is, am I actually contributing anything by further encrypting data that will be sent over HTTPS anyway?

Comment: What's stopping you from obtaining the free SSL Certificate like Let's Encrypt? That's more secure because client will not bypass the Certificate validation and you'll somewhat safe from Man-In-The-Middle attacks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the C# / PHP part has nothing to do with the question itself, and it is therefore better suited at IT-security site.

Comment: This question asks about client side encryption in Javascript.  You aren't using javascript but the answers are still very applicable: the point of TLS/SSL is to encrypt your data in transit, and encrypting it again yourself is almost always a waste of time.  So unless you have a very specific reason why you are doing it, don't waste your time:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91483/client-side-encryption-only-web-browser-available

Comment: @aepot I do not have a domain name, I just have a server and IP address, so as far as I know, can't get a signed certificate.

Comment: Correct but is getting some domain a problem? 3rd/4th level domain can be used too.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the use case. For transport security TLS is usually considered enough. Time is better spend at securing that connection than adding additional counter measures such as message specific encryption.

---

TLS does have limitations of course, so additional cryptography might be required:

- TLS doesn't offer client authentication without explicit configuration; client authentication may have to be performed after the connection has been established.
- It also offers, from a bird-eye view, only point to point protection (*); once the TLS security is stripped off the data is unprotected.
- Similarly, you may want to store the data securely either at the sender or receiver. Obviously TLS won't provide such functionality.

(*) TLS offers end-to-end encryption when it is viewed from the IP protocol, as TCP / UDP allows it to route (hop) the IP packets protected over multiple nodes, but it is nowadays often stripped off before it reaches the application (TLS offloaders etc.).

---

If you already have a shared secret then you might want to look at TLS in PSK mode, but beware that implementations of that standard are not as common as "regular" TLS. Beware too that you should only share keys between 2 parties at most.

---

Finally, the chances that you are providing meaningful security by just encrypting messages using AES is minimal at best. You do need a specific use case, protocol, scheme and finally implementation. The chance of getting that right by "just encrypting data" is slim. There are simply too many pitfalls for that. This is especially true if the encryption code or key is transported over the TLS connection (browser / JavaScript encryption).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data you are sending or receiving.
In most cases the HTTPS gives a lot of security to the data being sent over network and adding the additional layer just makes a it redundant and it will take up the processing time.

u can refer to the this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea) and this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51069/post-over-https-secure-enough-for-sensitive-data) for more info about stacking the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actual question is, as you ask something different in the title from what is in your text.

The question in your title seems to be asking if HTTPS (= TLS) with a self-signed certificate is enough as opposed to an "official" certificate. If that is so, then yes, there is no difference with regard to security. The difference is that clients need to *explicitly* trust a self-signed certificate, while certificates issued by one of the big root CAs (certificate authorities) will be *automatically* trusted, because they are delivered and trusted with the OS.

If, however, the question is more about if you need additional encryption besides HTTPS, then my answer would be: it depends.

HTTPS (or TLS) provides transport security, to prevent the data from being seen while being transmitted between client and (destination) server. However, on both ends of that, the data will not be encrypted. You are not giving information if the client and server environments (file system etc.) can be considered trustable. If so, HTTPs should be enough. Otherwise, additional encryption of the payload data would be
advisable.